# Flutter Shader>? How i can chieve that background?

Tags: flutter

im trying to make that custom background but i dont know how i can achieve that .

I used linearGradient in a Box Decoration but its effect its not so smooth.

Then i tried shaders but its kinda weird ,too dark even when i change the opacity.

Does anyone know with what widgets i can achieve that result?

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: What's not smooth about `LinearGradient`? I would think it's perfectly smooth

Comment: I did it with linear Gradient but it seemed like many straight lines.In the photo it seems totally different. Like the transition is a lot smoother.Can i achieve it with LinearGradient that? And how? Thanks.